# Замена слова на слова с нумерацией

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe5

**База такого типа:**

```
Text 01.02 Text 03.01
Text 01.02 Text 03.01
Text 01.02 Text 03.01
```

**Нужно заменить слово Text на: Text1, Text2, Text3 и так далее**. И на выходе результат:

**База такого типа:**

```
Text1 01.02 Text2 03.01
Text3 01.02 Text4 03.01
Text5 01.02 Text6 03.01
```

**Делал вот так но не срабатывает.**

```
s  := StringReplace(s, 'Text',  'Text' + IntToStr(i), [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать:

```
s  := StringReplace(s, 'Text ',  'Text' + IntToStr(i) + ' ', [rfIgnoreCase]);
```

- добавил в шаблоне пробел;
- удалил замену всех вхождений;
- добавил пробел в замене.

---

Пример использования:

```
procedure DoTest;
var
  i: Integer;
  s1, s2: string;
begin
  s1 :=
    'Text 01.02 Text 03.01' + #13#10 +
    'Text 01.02 Text 03.01' + #13#10 +
    'Text 01.02 Text 03.01';

  i := 1;
  repeat
    s2 := StringReplace(s1, 'Text ',  'Text' + IntToStr(i) + ' ', [rfIgnoreCase]);

    if s1 <> s2 then begin
      s1 := s2;
      Inc(i);
    end else begin
      Break;
    end;

  until False;

  Writeln(s2);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!